# how to access .skin file from aspx page

Tags: asp.net, skin

i have a `.skin` file inside my `app.themes` folder.  To access `.css` file from asp page we have to give link.  but i couldn't find any thing on asp header to give link for `.skin` file.

```
<asp:TextBox SkinID="txtBox" ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

i got the following error..
A SkinID has been specified but the page is not configured to use a page theme or stylesheet theme. This is acceptable if the theme or stylesheet theme will be set programmatically.

should i create any link?

thanks
saj

Comment: Please reformat your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should specify the name of the theme (ie the folder in your App_Themes folder that contains your skin file) on the Theme property of the Page.

In code:

```
Page.Theme = "MyTheme"
```

or in your markup:

```
<%@ Page Theme="MyTheme" .... %>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use ID="TextBox1"  in any skin file

Comment: Why not? Any concerns? Could you explain that?